# Mono audio output from alsa mixer

Tags: alsa

In my application the content of the asound.conf file is

pcm.usb
{
    type hw
    card 0
    format CD
    rate 48000
}

pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "usb"
    }
    capture.pcm "hw:1,0"
}

How to modify the asound.conf file inorder to get mono audio output from ALSA mixer?

Answer (score 0):

To allow automatic sample format conversion, use the `plug` plugin:

```perl
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type asym
        playback.pcm "hw:0"
        capture.pcm  "hw:1"
    }
}
```

Comment: After changing the asound.conf as above still I am getting stereo audio output from ALSA mixer.